# Using cloud9 on beaglebone ubuntu

Tags: beagleboard, cloud9-ide

I passionately set forth to try and install cloud9 ide on BeagleBone running Ubuntu. I followed the steps at this blog:http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1813076. However when it came down to installing o3 my build kept failing

```
Build failed:  -> task failed (err #1):
        {task: cxx sh_node.cc -> sh_node_1.o}
  File "/home/ubuntu/local/bin/node-waf", line 16, in <module>
        Scripting.prepare(t, os.getcwd(), VERSION, wafdir)
  File "/home/ubuntu/local/bin/../lib/node/wafadmin/Scripting.py", line 147, in prepare
        error(str(e))
```

So I would like to know if anyone has got cloud9 up and running on a beaglebone running ubuntu?

Comment: I'm having the same issue. I've figured out how to get o3 to compile by itself, but not sure how to get it integrated into the cloud9 installation process.

See this issue: https://github.com/ajaxorg/o3/issues/19

kiilo's comments about removing references to -msse2 and setting the node path are what got it compiling for me. I just don't know what to do next :P

Answer (score 0):

Do you have node.js 0.6.19 installed under Ubuntu?

It might fail due to libxml not being there. Try running `sudo apt-get install libxml2-dev`.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure the mini SD card is in the bBone *(the one that comes shipped with the bone) - it has Cloud9 already installed. Once you hook up the ethernet cable through a hub, you'll only have to direct your web browser to

```
    beaglebone.local:3000
```

Comment: As I metioned in my question, I am using a new sd card which has ubuntu on it.